# OpenAL C++ on Linux

Tags: c++, openal

I just need a simple program which allows me to play and stop an audio file.  I'm guessing OpenAL is the way to go?  All I need is this functionality - start audio file with spacebar and stop audio file with a second press of the spacebar.  I notice the OpenAL documentation is quite involved.  Can someone point me to something really simple in order to just get the start/stop functionality of a .wav file?

Comment: I know this is old, but there's a tutorial here, directed at game development, but I think gives you everything you need otherwise. https://indiegamedev.net/2020/02/15/the-complete-guide-to-openal-with-c-part-1-playing-a-sound/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenAL may not be the simplest choice. If you use a gui-framework like QT, check for what their ecosystems provide for playing sound (e.g. [qsound](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsound.html)). Another choice may be Allegro which may feel more straightforward.

For OpenAL, there is a working example to play a wav [in the example repositories](https://github.com/ffainelli/openal-example/blob/master/openal-example.c). Playback can be paused using `alSourcePause`.

Edit:

For choosing libraries I like to consult [Awesome-cpp](https://github.com/fffaraz/awesome-cpp#audio). The [simple_playback.c](https://github.com/dr-soft/mini_al/blob/master/examples/simple_playback.c) example of mini_al looks extremely straightforward. Simply use `mal_device_stop(&device)` to pause the running playback and `mal_device_start(&device)` to continue. Works perfectly on my machine and seems very portable.